# Nodejs MongoClient returning different results than MongoDB Compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on a nodejs backend that is running an aggregate pipeline on my mongo database. For some reason, when this pipeline is ran from my nodejs app, it returns 0 results. However, when I run the pipeline directly from MongoDB Compass, I get the many results I'd expect.

I am able to successfully run other aggregate pipelines from the nodejs app, so I'm confident my connection is set up properly, and the collection is correct.

I think I have narrowed it down to the dates being the leading issue. Anyone know how I can run this from the nodejs app?

The pipeline:

```
[
        {
          $match: {
            StartDate: {
              $gte: new Date("2023-09-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
              $lt: new Date("2023-09-23T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

And here is the entire endpoint for reference:

```
async function startServer() {
  try {
    const client = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');

    const db = client.db(); // Specify your database name if not the default

    app.post('/query', async (req, res) => {
      const testQuery = [
        {
          $match: {
            StartDate: {
              $gte: new Date("2023-09-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
              $lt: new Date("2023-09-23T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
          }
        }
      ]
      try {
        console.log("Received a request: ", JSON.stringify(req.body));
    
        const { collection, query } = req.body;
    
        if (!collection || !query) {
          return res.status(400).json({ error: "Collection or Query is missing" });
        }
    
        const result = await db.collection('Rides').aggregate(testQuery).toArray();
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
      }
    });    

    app.listen(5003, () => {
      console.log('Server started on http://localhost:5003');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the nodejs backend running in your local environment? If not, is it in the same timezone as your local?

Comment: @MuhammedAslamC Not entirely correct. You are passing UTC input to the `Date` constructor, but all further operations to fetch the data from that `Date` object works in local timezone.

Comment: So to confirm, just adjust the date ranges in your nodejs mongo query, and see if you are getting the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255393/discussion-between-muhammed-aslam-c-and-robin-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a resolution.

What I posted (the sample json) actually worked, I just never ran it. However, when pipelines were passed in from the frontend, json was serialized, then unserialized on the backend. During this process, dates were turned into strings.

What I did to solve this issue was convert any dates into ISO format strings, and then use a function to convert ISO formatted strings back to dates before running the pipeline.

```
function convertISOStringsToDate(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return obj.map(item => convertISOStringsToDate(item));
  } else if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
      const newObj = {};
      for (let key in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (isISODateString(obj[key])) {
                  newObj[key] = new Date(obj[key]);
              } else {
                  newObj[key] = convertISOStringsToDate(obj[key]);
              }
          }
      }
      return newObj;
  }
  return obj;
}
```